# How to skip accessibility focus on one bar button item and keep focus on other bar button items of the toolbar

Tags: ios, accessibility, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, uiaccessibility

I have a toolbar , I'd like to skip the title button when accessibility is turned on.

I can skip **accessibility** for the whole **tool bar** using **accessibilityElementsHidden**.

but I just want to skip the accessibility focus of title bar button.

I tried disabling the title button's accessibility individually.

But it's not working.

So I set the **AccessibilityElements** property , it's skipping the title bar and reading out the **DONE** button on right side. But there's no individual focus on that **DONE** button at all. The focus is missing for individual bar button items when I use **AccessibilityElements**.

Update:

I have added an observer here

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
```

Here is the observer

```
 [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(beginEditingHandler:) name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];
```

Here is how I'm managing the accessibility items

```
  - (void)beginEditingHandler:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UIResponder *responder = notification.object;
    IQToolbar *inputAccessoryView = responder.inputAccessoryView;
    if (inputAccessoryView) {
        if ([inputAccessoryView isKindOfClass:[IQToolbar class]]){
            NSMutableArray *arrAccessibilityItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            if(inputAccessoryView.previousBarButton){
                if(!inputAccessoryView.previousBarButton)
                [arrAccessibilityItems addObject:inputAccessoryView.previousBarButton];
            }
            if(inputAccessoryView.nextBarButton){
                if(!inputAccessoryView.nextBarButton.isHidden)
                [arrAccessibilityItems addObject:inputAccessoryView.nextBarButton];
            }
            if(inputAccessoryView.titleBarButton){
                IQTitleBarButtonItem *titleBtn= inputAccessoryView.titleBarButton;
                if(titleBtn.title.length>0){
                    [arrAccessibilityItems addObject:inputAccessoryView.titleBarButton];
                }
            }
            if(inputAccessoryView.doneBarButton){
                [arrAccessibilityItems addObject:inputAccessoryView.nextBarButton];
            }
            [inputAccessoryView setAccessibilityElements:arrAccessibilityItems];

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is this read out as whole tool bar rather than a bar item by bar item.

Comment: Your question is lacking any relevant details. Please show how you setup your toolbar. Clearly show what code you have tried and what element exactly you are trying to skip.

Comment: @HangarRash - I have added code snippet

Answer (score 1):

IQToolbar sets up a title button as [follows](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/blob/6f357ea18e0da4e089368da3b2b278d09102df65/IQKeyboardManagerSwift/IQToolbar/IQToolbar.swift#L101C5-L114C6):

```swift
    @objc open var titleBarButton: IQTitleBarButtonItem {
        get {
            if privateTitleBarButton == nil {
                privateTitleBarButton = IQTitleBarButtonItem(title: nil)
                privateTitleBarButton?.accessibilityLabel = "Title"
                privateTitleBarButton?.accessibilityIdentifier = privateTitleBarButton?.accessibilityLabel
            }
            return privateTitleBarButton!
        }

        set (newValue) {
            privateTitleBarButton = newValue
        }
    }
```

You'll have to subclass `IQToolbar` and override `titleBarButton` as follows:

```swift
open class MyToolbar: IQToolbar {
    open var titleBarButton: IQTitleBarButtonItem {
        get {
            let titleBarButton = super.titleBarButton
            titleBarButton.customView.subviews.first?.isAccessibilityElement = false
            return titleBarButton
        }
        set (newValue) {
            super.titleBarButton = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is with the accessibility in the tool bar ? Any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: @Shajo Did you try my answer? Does it solve your issue? If yes, please mark answer as accepted.